# rails relationship between models where primary key not involved

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models - Batch and Player

```
Batch has_many :players, :foreign_key => "PL_BATCH"
Player belongs_to :batch, :foreign_key => "PL_BATCH"
```

The table `batches` contains the following fields:

```
-BA_OID (defined as the primary key)
-BA_BATCH_ID
-BA_NAME
```

The table `players` contains the field `PL_BATCH` which is the foreign key of `BA_BATCH_ID`.

Note that I am using a legacy database and the column 'BA_OID ' is defined as the primary key of the batches table in mysql. However `BA_BATCH_ID` is used as FK in the players table

Batch model:

```
  set_table_name "batches"
  set_primary_key "BA_OID"
  has_many :players, :foreign_key => "PL_BATCH"
```

How do i define the relationship between batch and player models??

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there! Try the following...

`Batch`:

```
has_many :players, :primary_key => "BA_BATCH_ID", :foreign_key => "PL_BATCH", :class_name => "Player"
```

`Player`:

```
belongs_to :batch, :primary_key => "BA_BATCH_ID", :foreign_key => "PL_BATCH", :class_name => "Batch"
```

Comment: I now seems to be getting another error - my habtm checkbxes are not longer working when i am creating a batch and selecting multiple players to add to it. Before when the primary key was set as BA_BATCH_ID:     set_table_name "batches";  set_primary_key "BA_BATCH_ID", my habtm checkboxes were working but now the players are not saved when i am creating a new batch and associating players to it

Comment: @tanya, you'll need to provide your whole form and controller code for us to have any idea how to debug that. I suggest you start a new question for this.